# Question on faithful representation and irreducible characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Q:Let $G$ be a finite group and let $(\rho,V)$ be a complex representation of $G$ that is faithful. Let $\chi$ be the character of it. Show that any irreducible
complex character $\psi$ of $G$ has $(\chi^n, \psi) > 0$ for some integer $n$>0.

I only got few ideas. My attempt:

$V$ is faithful over an algebraically closed field $\iff$ every irreducible representation of $G$ is a subrepresentation of the symmetric power $S^m(V)$ for some large $m$. But I don't how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetric power $S^m(V)$ is a subrepresentation of the tensor power $T^m(V)$. The character of $T^m(V)$ is $\chi^m$.

Comment: So can I conclude (\chi^n,\psi)=(\chi^n,\chi^m)>0 if n=m?

Comment: @BelloBello You seem pretty confused. I do not know why you would consider $(\chi^n, \chi^m)$. You should talk about this with your instructor.

Comment: Yes... I'll talk to my instructor. Anyway, thank you at all!